# Hyperref - borders arounds (name)ref and no borders around cites and ToC entries

Tags: hyperref

Both cites and references should be clickable. I want to have visible borders around the links (refs and namerefs) and no borders around citations (cites). Yet, there shouldn't be any borders in ToC.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=false, linkbordercolor={1 0 1}, citebordercolor={1 1 0}} 
                                               %101 = pink,         110=yellow

\begin{document}
\chapter{Abc}
\cite{abc} a.k.a. \nameref{yoyo}

\tableofcontents

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{abc}
ABC.
\end{thebibliography}

\appendix
\chapter{yoyo}
\label{yoyo}

\end{document}
```

In the example above, there shouldn't be any border around cite #1 and in ToC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Option `hidelinks` removes optical elements for recognizing links (no color, border). It can be given locally, e.g. for the `\tableofcontents`, see the example.
- `\cite` is more difficult. But it can be redefined and wrapped into a group with `\hypersetup{hidelinks}`.
- If you load package `xcolor`, then the options for `*bordercolor` can be color names.

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=false,
  linkbordercolor={pink},
  % citebordercolor={yellow} % not needed
}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\org@cite}{}
\LetLtxMacro\org@cite\cite % because of optional argument
\renewcommand*{\cite}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    \hypersetup{hidelinks}%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
      \org@cite{#2}%
    \else
      \org@cite[{#1}]{#2}%
    \fi
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Abc}
\cite{abc} a.k.a. \nameref{yoyo}

\begingroup
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}
  \tableofcontents
\endgroup

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{abc}
ABC.
\end{thebibliography}

\appendix
\chapter{yoyo}
\label{yoyo}

\end{document}
```